# Is it possible to use validation groups in Micronaut using annotations?

Tags: java, validation, microservices, micronaut

Is it possible to use validation groups in Micronaut using annotations?

Option without Spring annotations is preferred.

Comment: Yes, you can check the example from [bean validation specification](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#validationapi-validatorapi-groups).

Comment: Missed in my question, sorry. I want to use @Valid or another in controllers with groups without direct validate() call, like in Spring.